# How can I place the new added pdf file into last page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I added a new page in an existing pdf document. It successfully merge with the old document but the problem is , instead on showing in the last page , it shows as the first page. Are there any functions or way I can put it in the last position?

Comment: share your code also

Comment: Most likely you add it in first position instead of in last position. To be more concrete we need your relevant code.

Comment: Im sorry, I wasn't able to put my code. I already fix my problem. Its the naming convention of the temporary files. And because of this part

("~/PDF_Temporary/"), UserName + "_Contract*.pdf" , about the "_Contract*.pdf" im not really sure about its function. does it signifies all pdf files that has a name "_Contract"?